# SQL Statement - SELECT the inverse of this query

Tags: mysql, sql, inverse-transform

I have this query and i want to select the inverse of what that select.

```
SELECT Guide.id FROM Guide
INNER JOIN GuideAvailability ON Guide.id = GuideAvailability.guideId
WHERE GuideAvailability.startDate IN (1377946800)
GROUP BY GuideAvailability.guideId
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT GuideAvailability.id) = 1
```

Is there a easy way to solve my problem ?

Comment: Define "Inverse"? Give examples.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by the inverse. One answer is change "IN" to "NOT IN". Another answer is to change "HAVING ... = 1" to "HAVING ... <> 1". Or do both. What do you want?

Comment: This query returns the id of the Guide that correspond to my condition. I want to get all guide excepts the ones that are selected in this query

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Simply use this query:

```
SELECT * 
     FROM Guide where id NOT IN (
       SELECT Guide.id 
         FROM Guide
         INNER JOIN GuideAvailability ON Guide.id = GuideAvailability.guideId
         WHERE GuideAvailability.startDate IN (1377946800) 
         GROUP BY GuideAvailability.guideId 
         HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT GuideAvailability.id) = 1
      )
```

Comment: Isn't there an "EXCEPT" in MySQL?  I believe NOT IN will give you some performance issues

Comment: @Schalk no there is no such thing in mysql

Answer (score 0):

MAy be you are looking for this

```
SELECT Guide.id FROM Guide
INNER JOIN GuideAvailability ON Guide.id = GuideAvailability.guideId
WHERE GuideAvailability.startDate NOT IN (1377946800) GROUP BY GuideAvailability.guideId HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT GuideAvailability.id) <> 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can flip the bool. ;)

I do this when I have a large amount of where filters and there is a specific exclusion set of filters. I write them inside the case and do `=1` to exclude and `=0` to find what I excluded.

```
SELECT Guide.id FROM Guide
INNER JOIN GuideAvailability ON Guide.id = GuideAvailability.guideId
WHERE ( case when GuideAvailability.startDate IN (1377946800) then 1 else 0 end) = 0
GROUP BY GuideAvailability.guideId
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT GuideAvailability.id) = 1
```