# Rails has_and_belongs_to_many associations: how to retrieve records not having a specific associated record

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5

Let's say have Student and a Teacher models:

```
class Student < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :teachers
end

class Teacher < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :students
end
```

and the DB schema looks something like this

```
create_table "students", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end

create_table "students_teachers", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
  t.bigint "student_id", null: false
  t.bigint "teacher_id", null: false
  t.index ["student_id", "teacher_id"], name: "index_students_teachers_on_student_id_and_teacher_id"
  t.index ["teacher_id", "student_id"], name: "index_students_teachers_on_teacher_id_and_student_id"
end

create_table "teachers", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end
```

and I have seeded the DB with following:

```
students = Student.create([{}, {}, {}, {}])
teacher_1 = Teacher.create
teacher_2 = Teacher.create
teacher_3 = Teacher.create

teacher_1.students << [students[0], students[1]]
teacher_2.students << students[1]
```

Now I want to get all teachers which don't have `students[0]`. But when I run

```
Teacher.includes(:students).where.not(students: {id: students[0].id})
```

it returns `teacher_1` and `teacher_2`. Is there any way to get all teachers which don't have the specified student? (`teacher_2` & `teacher_3` in this case).

I also tried

```
Teacher.includes(:students).where("students.id != ? OR students.id IS NULL", students[0].id).references(:students)
```

but it returns all three teachers.

I tried hard finding anything that can help me on the internet but no luck so far :(

**Update 1:**

As @ruby_newbie commented below, the query results includes `teacher_1` because `teacher_1` have one other student (`student[1]`) but I want to get all teachers which do not have a particular student say `student[0]` no matter if they have other students.

Comment: what is the output if you do `teacher_3 << students[0]`?  I think your query is working but that because both teacher_1 and teacher_2 have student_1 they both return as results.

Comment: I know that but is there any way to return teachers which don't have student[0] no matter they have another student or not.

Comment: I am not sure it will work or not I found something similar https://stackoverflow.com/a/11279406/3759158

Comment: Teacher.joins(:students).where("students_teachers.student_id is NULL OR students_teachers.student_id <> ?", students[0].id)

Comment: @Manishh both `<>` and `!=` operators do the same thing :) https://stackoverflow.com/a/723426/2902497

Comment: 1st, this isn't really a rails/ruby question - it's just a SQL question.

Once you realize it's a SQL/db question - the answer is always let your tools do what they were made for & get out of their way!

You can just do an `.where` with inverse lookup with SQL, ...NOT activerecord - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19682816/sql-statement-select-the-inverse-of-this-query.

2nd,relationship - ditch the HAB2M relationship.  Go with `has_many` paired with `has_many: :through` setup per rails guide & then you could do a rails call from student looking for teacher records not having student

Comment: you can try with `Teacher.joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN students_teachers ON students_teachers.teacher_id = teachers.id').where(students_teachers: { student_id: students[0], teacher_id: nil })`

Comment: @mr_sudaca it doesn't work either. Returns no results. Here is the SQL it formed `SELECT  "teachers".* FROM "teachers" LEFT OUTER JOIN students_teachers ON students_teachers.teacher_id = teac
hers.id WHERE "students_teachers"."student_id" = 1 AND "students_teachers"."teacher_id" IS NULL LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 11]]`